# Kaddish on a plane

Tags: travel, posek-psak-decisor-ruling, kaddish

Much has been made on Jewish blogs and in Jewish press outlets about a recent ruling from the new Sepharadi Chief Rabbi of Israel, R' Yitzhak Yoseph, that people should not gather to make a Minyan on an airplane if it disturbs other travelers, especially by waking them up, and disturbs the flight attendants while they are trying to do their jobs.  He says that each person should remain seated and Daven privately.

This ruling is not new; major Posekim have said this in the past, including R' Yoseph's father, himself a former Sepharadi Chief Rabbi of Israel, R' 'Ovadiah Yoseph, as have rabbis of less renown.

What about when someone has to say Kaddish?  Should the person forgo an opportunity, and the group forgo an opportunity to facilitate, this important "Mitzvah" (I use quotes because, while perhaps not a real Mitzvah, it is certainly regarded by the general public as a major duty)?  Should the person avoid such trips if possible?

<sub>{This is not personally relevant, B"H; I saw this question posted to an email group and found it interesting.}</sub>

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18243/759

Comment: @DoubleAA, I like your Av/Em comment.  It crossed my mind as well, as I was typing this question.

Answer (score 1):

Mi rabbi, Rabi Michael Perets, shlita, who has written many books on halacha, has said that a person who has to say kaddish may say some in advance or otherwise "repay" them when he can. He states that a person is only obligated to say three each day, so if a person may lose two on a plane trip he could try to say 5 the previous day of his trip. I know that this don't touch directly on the first question, but it might be helpful for whomever wants to be careful of not disturbing others, especially that that might be chillul Hashem, chas veshalom.

Answer (score 0):

Many poskim are opposed to praying in the aisle where other passengers may be disturbed:

- [R' Herschel Schachter](http://www.torahweb.org/torah/special/2010/rsch_airplanes.html)
- [R' Yitzchak Yosef](http://matzav.com/rav-yitzchak-yosef-daven-byechidus-on-plane-if-minyan-will-disturb-flight)
- [R' Shlomo Zalman Auerbach](http://www.shut-halacha.co.il/question.php?id=1026)

[Similar opinions](http://hirhurim.blogspot.co.il/2008/09/praying-on-airplane.html) have been expressed by R' Moshe Feinstein, R' Ovadia Yosef, R' Shmuel Wosner and R' Yitzchak Zilberstein.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question. Do any of those authorities discuss one who is saying Kaddish?