# Joining an airplane Minyan

Tags: travel, minyan

Related to my [Kaddish on a plane](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31070/5) question, as well as this [Praying on an airplane](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3233/5) question, assuming one is aware, and respectful, of the ruling *not* to form a Minyan on an airplane, what should one do if an airplane Minyan is forming (or has formed)?

1. Should one join the Minyan:
   a. if his participation gives the Minyan its 10th man?
   b. if it is happening without his participation anyway?
2. Should one discourage the Minyan, which could potentially create a larger disturbance?

Comment: sounds like maarit ayin to join to me.

Comment: Is this question premised on a scenario where a minyan will be cause a disturbance? That is often not the case if permission is received in advance and the minyan is coordinated with the flight crew (particularly on flights to/from Israel). I have seen cases where the davening is not loud and none of the passengers or crew seem to mind (except sometimes one person complains loudly, apparently without any reason - is it really necessary to abort a minyan due to a cantankerous troublemaker?).

Comment: [relevant article from R Jason Weiner](http://rabbiweiner.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/RJJ-Minyan-on-an-Airplane-Jason-Weiner.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.beithillel.org.il/show.asp?id=60708

> גם אבלים יוותרו על אמירת קדיש יתום במטוס ולא ינסו לארגן מנין. ניתן
>   לעיין בגיליון זה בתשובה בנושא קדיש יתומה, בעניין שתמיד יש לבחון אם
>   אמירת הקדיש גורמת לקידוש השם או ח"ו להיפך, שאז יש לוותר על אמירת
>   הקדיש.

An Aveil should give up his Kaddish rather than make a Chillul Hashem.

Comment: Who is this quotation from?

Comment: על סדר היום
הרב רונן לוביץ´ (בית הלל)
הרב שלמה הכט (בית הלל)
הרב אביע"ד סנדרס (בית הלל)
הרב אהד טהרלב (בית הלל)
הרבנית ירדנה קופ יוסף (בית הלל)
הרב נתן לופס קרדוזו (בית הלל)
הרבנית אשרה קורן (בית הלל)
הרב שלום שרון (בית הלל)
הרב ג´פרי וולף (בית הלל)
הרבנית מיכל טיקוצ´ינסקי (בית הלל)
הרב מאיר נהוראי (בית הלל) http://www.beithillel.org.il/all.asp?cat=4755