# Mourner that misses Kaddish

Tags: halacha, mourning-aveilus, kaddish

A mourner who is having an operation, or travelling, or any other reason that makes it impossible for him to say Kaddish at a particular Tefila. Is there anything the mourner should do to make up for the missed Kaddish?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18243/759

Answer (score 3):

The minimum requirement for kaddish is to say it once at any one of the three minyonim. If a person cannot attend any of the three minyonim on a particular day, he cannot "make it up" on a different day. Chabad.org (shown below) recommends that one learn or give tzedakah or emphasize a mitzvah in honor of the deceased parent. This can help in the event that one has had to "miss" the opportunity to say kaddish at a minyan.

Note that the main requirement is a son for one of his parents.

[Kaddish: The How To](http://www.mykaddish.com/kaddish-how.html)

> Kaddish is not an all-or-nothing proposition. If for some reason a
>   person misses a daily service, he continues saying kaddish in all
>   subsequent services.
>
> Ideally, kaddish is said three times a day. If it is not possible to
>   attend synagogue for more than one daily service, once is the minimum
>   requirement. If one is unable to make the commitment to say kaddish
>   daily for eleven months, it is possible to pay someone in a synagogue
>   to say it on your behalf.

Note that three times a day above means at each of the three services. It does not need to be said more than once each service.

[When the Mourner Cannot Attend Services](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/281618/jewish/Kaddish-Observances.htm)

> What should be done, in such cases, is what the Kaddish itself seeks
>   to do: enhance the "Merit of the Children." The mourners should read a
>   portion of the Bible--a chapter from the Five Books of Moses or the
>   Prophets--or, if he is able, study a mishnah or page from the Talmud.
>   This is a constructive and entirely valid substitute for the Kaddish,
>   when one finds it extremely difficult to attend one of the services.
>
> Tradition recommends other ways to glorify a parent's teaching.
>   Children should make a standard practice of contributing to charity in
>   their parents' memory. Even more effective and more beautiful,
>   mourners should strive to adopt one mitzvah, one special deed, which
>   they will take to heart and practice regularly as a memorial tribute.
>   This custom adds life to the influence of a parent who has passed on
>   and builds a future life for those who survive.

Comment: "The minimum requirement for kaddish is to say it once at any one of the three minyonim." How do you know this?

Comment: "Ideally, kaddish is said three times a day."  This makes it sound like you could say kaddish at the three times during shacharit and would have fufilled your obligation [(if the obligation exists)](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18243/how-obligated-is-one-to-say-kaddish-for-a-deceased-relative#comment44428_18243).  I realize this is not your words, just a quote you got from mykaddish.com, but I am not sure if it is correct or if the usual assumption "once per each of the three services" is more accurate.

Comment: @Mike Ideally once per service. Minimally, once per day. This accounts for those places where each mourner says one kaddish instead of all saying kaddish at once.

Comment: Sorry Sabbahillel, I have misunderstood your last comment. Does one have to minimally say Kaddish 3 times a day, at the end of each service OR minimally at least once a day? Please may I have your source.