# What does it mean for a mourner to "have a chiuv"?

Tags: tefilla, chazzan-prayer-leader, mourning-aveilus, yahrtzeit

I have noticed that in many synagogues, before *davening*, the *gabbai* customarily asks if anybody "has a *chiuv*".  If there is anybody with a *chiuv*, he is asked to *daven* from the *amud*.  The people who are considered to "have a *chiuv*" are *aveilim* and those observing *yahrtzeit* for a parent. What exactly does such a person have a *chiuv* for?  I have thought of a couple of possibilities, but neither of them seem to make sense to me.

1. They have an obligation to pray. To me, this seems like a very unlikely suggestion. Everybody there has an obligation to pray, and I don't know why a mourner would have a greater obligation.
2. They have an obligation to lead *davening*. This suggestion is plausible to me, but I still have some doubts. First of all, there might be more than one person with a *chiuv*. In that case, would it really be the case that everybody who doesn't lead *davening* is *mivatel* a *chiuv*? I have doubts about that because I have seen people who I know to be very pious and knowledgeable who had a *chiuv* praying in a *minyan* where someone else with a *chiuv* was leading the prayer. If this is truly an obligation, I would expect that those people would find another *minyan* where nobody has a *chiuv*. Also, why would having a relative pass away cause someone to have an obligation to lead *davening*?

So what is the obligation that is being referred to when we say that someone "has a *chiuv*"? If it is not really actually a true **obligation**, why is it called that?

Comment: Possible dupe  http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18243/759

Comment: @DoubleAA Your question takes as a given that the _chiuv_ is for saying _kaddish_. If that is indeed the case, then that could be an answer (ideally with some evidence and preferably with an explanation why such a _chiuv_ would be a reason for that person to lead davening).

Comment: it would seem from the material discussed here http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5762/pekudei.html that this is an issue of "minhag yisroel kihalachah," that since it is accepted practice among Jews to lead during yahrtzeit, shloshim, etc. then it is incumbent upon those who are capable to do so, and therefore a *chiyuv.*

Comment: I have often wondered who has the "chiuv". The person saying kaddish or the congregation, who have a "chiuv" to give that person "priority" to lead. Just like we have a "chiuv" to call up a Kohen for the first aliyah (a strong chiyuv) or offer him to lead Birkat Hamazon (a slightly weaker chiyuv).

Answer (score 5):

*Davening* from the amud is not an obligation indeed, and if someone else has priority [one is not obligated to find another minyan](http://dinonline.org/2015/07/20/avel-davening-for-amud/) in order to *daven* from the amud. It is a custom as a way of honoring one’s parent.

[R Avraham Yosef](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avraham_Yosef) (previously Chief Rabbi of Holon, son of R Ovadia Yosef) was asked last Friday on his weekly radio halacha Q&A "what does one lose when giving up *davening* from the amud to let someone else lead?" and answered "one never loses when letting someone else lead *davening*.")

[R Neustadt writes, p. 6](http://www.parsha.net/pdf/Shmos/VayakhelPekudei62.pdf)

> The Shulchan Aruch records the long-standing and universally held
>   custom for the son of a deceased parent to lead the weekday prayer
>   services as the Sheliach Tzibbur. This obligation is in addition to
>   the recitation of Kaddish, and is practiced throughout the eleven
>   months when Kaddish is recited. A son in mourning should do his utmost
>   to observe this custom; for Chazal teach that when a son serves as the
>   Sheliach Tzibbur, he is actually fulfilling the Biblical commandment
>   of Kibbud Av V'eim by honoring the neshamah of his departed parent and
>   alleviating its suffering in Gehenom.

**So maybe it is called a chiyuv (obligation) because there is an obligation to *try to* lead the davening** but it is not literally correct. Or as indicated by @Isaac Kotlicky [above](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68120/what-does-it-mean-for-a-mourner-to-have-a-chiuv/68126#comment193189_68120) because of *minhag Israel kihalachah*.

Comment: "Universally held"? This site http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/toshba/minhagim/tey-mish.htm says Temanim only have the custom to lead Maariv on Sat nights. (Not the first time R Neustadt has monolithicified Jewish practice...)

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, the "_chiuv_" that is being referred to is to lead _davening_, but to call it a _chiuv_ is not **literally** correct?

Comment: @Daniel that is what I tried to say yes - but you say it better

Comment: The answer (I know you're relaying sources) appears to contradict the general notion that when someone is asked to become chazzan, he is supposed to **refuse** the honor first. I'm not sure why anyone would state that he should even try to be chazzan. As a matter of fact, after a while, when the person has been in the same shul and has already lead, they stop asking as they automatically assume that the "chiyuv" will do it. That also appears contradictory to the notion that the chazzan should be someone approved by congregational consensus. I know it's custom, but I question  its reasoning.

Comment: @DanF my understanding is that refusing when asked doesn't apply to these situations but to non-chiyuv cases. When people have chiyuvim they actually fight to daven from the amud which is why the Halacha has precise list of priorities and a number of exhortations not to fight

Comment: @mbloch I posted a follow-up question - http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/68133/5275

Comment: @DanF which I tried to [answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/68134/11501) to the best of my abilities :->

Comment: "...Chazal teach that when a son serves as the Sheliach Tzibbur, he is actually fulfilling the Biblical commandment of Kibbud Av V'eim..." The link is broken. Can you please provide a source?

Comment: @larry909 apologies but the content has not been migrated to their new site. I was able to find a copy of the content [here](http://www.parsha.net/pdf/Shmos/VayakhelPekudei62.pdf) on page 6

Answer (score 2):

In addition to other answers (at the time of writing, there is only one, by M Bloch):

According to the Mishnah Berurah, the minyan has a chiyuv to give him precedence. (53:60) And so, when there is a conflict, it is not to people with conflicting chiyuvim, it is one body that has to prioritize its duties.