# Are there any sources as to shul members having kedima

Tags: sources-mekorot, synagogue, chazzan-prayer-leader

I understand the purpose of being a member of a shul outside the scope of halacha but I am wondering if there are sources anywhere that talks about that a shul can/cannot deny a chiyuv (ie for a yartzheit) from davening for the amud if he is not a member of the shul?

How about any sources that talk about details of people being a member if a shul?

Thanks in advanced

Comment: Possible duplicate: "'[Chiyuv' to be chazan vs. congregational approval and refusal](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/68133/1368)".

Comment: The classical sources talk about a resident of a town vs a guest, as to opposed to "membership", possibly because in many places there was only one shul in town to go to.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/77570/759 cc @Joel I agree toshav would be a member these days

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/77567/priority-for-multiple-chiyuvim-to-be-shaliach-tzibbur/77570#77570 also a potential dup

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) lotto_guy and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: @mbloch Thank you for the warm welcome!