# Why does leading the Amud alleviate suffering for the deceased?

Tags: mourning-aveilus

A question was asked [here on the forum](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/68120/9431) for clarification on the Chiyuv for an Avel to pray for the Amud. And in an answer that was given, the answerer provided a quote from Rabbi Neustadt:

> "...for Chazal teach that when a son serves as the Sheliach Tzibbur,
>   he is actually fulfilling the Biblical commandment of Kibbud Av V'eim
>   by honoring the neshamah of his departed parent and alleviating its
>   suffering in Gehenom."

Question: 
Why does leading the Amud alleviate suffering of the deceased?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

R Yaakov Goldstein in his book [The Laws & Customs of Mourning Vol. 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1796949051) writes ([here online](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/chapter-25-davening-during-the-year-of-aveilus/))

> An Avel [who is the son of the deceased, whether the deceased is his
>   father or mother], is to lead the prayers as Chazan for every
>   weekday prayer, if he knows how to do so. [This applies even if
>   there are other potential Chazanim available. He is to push himself
>   to lead all the prayers, even if he does not have a good voice.]
>   Having the Avel [for a parent] lead the prayers is of greater benefit
>   [to the deceased] than the saying of Kaddish Yasom, as Kaddish Yasom
>   was mainly instituted for children [under Bar Mitzvah] who cannot yet
>   lead the prayers.
>
> **The reason why Davening is beneficial for the soul
>   is not because it contains a prayer or supplication of pardon on
>   behalf of the deceased, but simply because the son is performing a
>   great Mitzvah by Davening and sanctifying Hashem’s name in public, and
>   every Mitzvah a son does benefits his parent.** It is understood from
>   here that the same applies towards any Mitzvah that a child does after
>   the passing of his parent, that it brings his parent atonement and
>   benefits his soul.
>
> **Furthermore, learning Torah and performing
>   charity and good deeds is of even greater benefit for the soul than
>   Kaddish Yasom and leading the prayers**, as Kaddish Yasom was mainly
>   instituted for children [under Bar Mitzvah], and hence one must place
>   his emphasis mainly on these activities.

See [there](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/chapter-25-davening-during-the-year-of-aveilus/) at length for details and sources.